# TypeScript: Declare Different Libraries/References for Different Files Within the Same Project

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a project that is written in TypeScript. I use both the dom and Web Workers, so I need the webworker.d.ts library in some files and dom.d.ts in other files.

I already tried adding "webworker" to the lib option in tsconfig.json, but those two are incompatible.

Another thing I tried is adding:

```
/// <reference no-default-lib="true"/>
/// <reference lib="esnext" />
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
```

at the top of my service worker file, but "webworker" is applied to every file instead of just the one that includes the references.

How can I have both files that need references to dom and files that need references to webworker within the same project?

Here is my config:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With vue see [Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20595](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20595) which states:

`We have found that what is meaningful in the global scope of a web worker is significantly more narrow than we find out of the DOM. So we tend to author with "lib": [ "dom" ] and then just declare the handful of APIs we require to make a web worker work, or we obtain a reference to the global object, treat it as any, and pick off certain properties from the global scope and type them at the point where we pick them off.`

Try like:

```
const ctx: Worker = self as any;
ctx.postMessage();
```

OR: Follow the [linked 20595](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20595) recipe which will require typesetting to  some webworker parts or making types files for components you need/use.

Use:

```
const globalObject: any = (function (): any {
if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    // global spec defines a reference to the global object called 'global'
    // https://github.com/tc39/proposal-global
    // `global` is also defined in NodeJS
    return global;
}
else if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // window is defined in browsers
    return window;
}
else if (typeof self !== 'undefined') {
    // self is defined in WebWorkers
    return self;
}
})();
```

Then reference by, for example:

```
import globalObject from 'globalObject'
globalObject.postMessage({});
```

Comment: I followed your advice by only typing the thing I need: `self` using `import { ServiceWorkerGlobalScope } from "./webworker.ts"; declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;`. `webworker.ts` is a ~250 line long file where I copied only `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope`, `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`, `WorkerGlobalScope` and missing interfaces from `webworker.d.ts`.

I then access e.g. `clients` using `self.clients` instead of just `clients`.