# A type error in WorkBox routing when defining HeadersInit value

Tags: typescript, workbox

I'm currently trying to create a Service Worker with TypeScript and WorkBox. The following is my current WorkBox definition (just to get something going). How could I solve the type error that I explain the following?

In the `registerRoute` piece TypeScript compiler tells that `matchPrecache` expect two parameters, the other being of type `HeadersInit`. If it is not given, default `Content-Type: text/html` is assumed. I would like to be explicit and give the type, but when I do so, I get an error the `matchPrecache` return value is not assignable.

If I check [strategy.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/workbox-sw/v3/index.d.ts#L1155), it looks like so

```
/**
 * A shortcut to create a strategy that could be dropped-in to Workbox's router.
 *
 * On browsers that do not support constructing new `ReadableStream`s, this
 * strategy will automatically wait for all the `sourceFunctions` to complete,
 * and create a final response that concatenates their values together.
 *
 * @param {Array<function({event, request, url, params})>} sourceFunctions
 * An array of functions similar to {@link module:workbox-routing~handlerCallback}
 * but that instead return a {@link module:workbox-streams.StreamSource} (or a
 * Promise which resolves to one).
 * @param {HeadersInit} [headersInit] If there's no `Content-Type` specified,
 * `'text/html'` will be used by default.
 * @return {module:workbox-routing~handlerCallback}
 * @memberof module:workbox-streams
 */
declare function strategy(sourceFunctions: StreamsHandlerCallback[], headersInit: HeadersInit): RouteHandlerCallback;
export { strategy };
```

```
import { clientsClaim, skipWaiting } from 'workbox-core';
import { strategy as streamsStrategy } from 'workbox-streams';
import { cleanupOutdatedCaches, matchPrecache, precacheAndRoute } from "workbox-precaching";
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";

declare const self: any;

self.addEventListener("message", (event: { data: any; type: any; ports: any }) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
cleanupOutdatedCaches();

const requestHeaders: HeadersInit =
{
  "Content-Type": "text/html"
}

registerRoute(
  '/', streamsStrategy([() => matchPrecache("index.html")], requestHeaders)
);

skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();
```

---

**Edit :** All right! When I'm not just looking at VS Code error but try to build, I discovered a bunch of other errors in the command line. One long piece of text

```
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:25:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following
identifiers conflict with those in another file: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject,
ImportExportKind, TableKind, ValueType, 
ExportValue, Exports, ImportValue, ModuleImports, 
Imports, name, ==> HeadersInit <==, BodyInit, RequestInfo, BlobPart, DOMHighResTimeStamp, CanvasImageSource, OffscreenRenderingContext, MessageEventSource, 
ImageBitmapSource, OnErrorEventHandler, TimerHandler, PerformanceEntryList, ReadableStreamReadResult, VibratePattern, AlgorithmIdentifier, HashAlgorithmIdentifier, BigInteger, NamedCurve,
 GLenum, GLboolean, GLbitfield, GLint, GLsizei, GLintptr, GLsizeiptr, GLuint, GLfloat, GLclampf, TexImageSource, Float32List, Int32List, GLint64, GLuint64, Uint32List, BufferSource, DOMTimeStamp, 
FormDataEntryValue, IDBValidKey, Transferable, BinaryType, CanvasDirection, CanvasFillRule, CanvasLineCap, CanvasLineJoin, CanvasTextAlign, CanvasTextBaseline, ClientTypes, ColorSpaceConversion, EndingType, IDBCursorDirection, IDBRequestReadyState, IDBTransactionMode, ImageOrientation, ImageSmoothingQuality, KeyFormat, KeyType, KeyUsage, NotificationDirection, NotificationPermission, OffscreenRenderingContextId, PermissionName, PermissionState, PremultiplyAlpha, PushEncryptionKeyName, PushPermissionState, ReferrerPolicy, RequestCache, RequestCredentials, RequestDestination, RequestMode, RequestRedirect, ResizeQuality, ResponseType, ServiceWorkerState, ServiceWorkerUpdateViaCache, VisibilityState, WebGLPowerPreference, WorkerType, XMLHttpRequestResponseType
```

I tried to emphasize one of them is this problematic `HeadersInit`. My `tsconfig.json` is as follows

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "esnext",
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noEmitOnError": true,
      "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": false,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "importHelpers": true,
      "outDir": "out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "inlineSources": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "removeComments": true,
      "rootDir": "./"
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
  }
```

and in my `package.json` I have

```
"@types/workbox-sw": "^4.3.1",
"@types/workbox-window": "^4.3.3",
```

so maybe this has something to do with this.

---

**Edit 2 :** That previous error happens only if I put
`/// <reference lib="webworker" />` on top of the file. After removing it I get a same problem as described at [WorkBox issue #2584](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2584) (as far as error messages go).

---

**Edit 3 :** I removed the explicit reference, found [WorkBox issue #2172](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2172) and tried adding this library to `tsconfig.json` and now there are again a lot of messages about type conflicts between `dom` and `webworker` library definitions.

---

**Edit 4 :** I noticed https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20595 and consequently also [TypeScript: Declare Different Libraries/References for Different Files Within the Same Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188827/typescript-declare-different-libraries-references-for-different-files-within-th) about the TypeScript `dom` and `webworker` library conflict. It appears removing `webworker` from `tsconfig.json` does not fix the original problem with `streamsStrategy` and `HeadersInit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create separate folder for you service worker and extend main tsconfig.json for this folder.
To do this, you need create another tsconfig.json inside folder with your serviceworker.ts, with next content:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "lib": ["webworker"],
  "include": ["."]
}
```

And, I hope, you know, that service worker must compile to separate file as webworker.
Can you provide link to your project?

Comment: This may actually work since the problem is about conflicts in the definitions (as discussed in GH). I need some days to try this but no need to keep this open that long. :)